# recieve all data from tf message

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`listener.lookupTransform('/frame1', '/frame2', rospy.Time(0))`
function  works with 2 frames, so if i need to know all frames positions, relative to frame1, i have to call "lookupTransform" for each frame? Is that right way?
I mean, if i have 10 frames, i should call lookupTransform 9 times, is this normal to performance?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209321/recieve-all-data-from-tf-message/) by [tambel](https://answers.ros.org/users/22448/tambel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, typical usage is to have many more frames in the system than you are operating upon.

And making 10 queries to find the relationship between 10 frames takes the same amount of computation whether done internally or externally. So we kept the API simple and only provide lookups between two frames.

And note that lookup is optimized and a relatively cheap operation.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1